# More than one duplicated element in C

Tags: c

Let's say I have an array like this:

```
int array[]={1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 5};
```

I want to display all duplicate elements only once, display their corresponding frequency and count total duplicate elements. I searched about it a lot but every solution is for an array that has only 2 duplicate elements.

```
void non_unique_numbers(int arr[], int size){
    int i,j;
    int frequency[Frequency_size]={0};
    for(i=0; i<size; i++){
        for(j=0; j<size; j++){
            if(arr[i]==arr[j] && i!=j){
                ++frequency[arr[j]];
                printf("Number: %d  , Frequency: %d\n", arr[j], frequency[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this my output is:

```
Number: 1  , Frequency: 3
Number: 2  , Frequency: 1
Number: 2  , Frequency: 1
Number: 2  , Frequency: 1
Number: 2  , Frequency: 2
Number: 1  , Frequency: 0
Number: 2  , Frequency: 2
Number: 2  , Frequency: 6
Number: 4  , Frequency: 0
```

which is meaningless. How can I display every duplicate element once and find out their corresponding frequency?

Comment: For some reason this had the irrelevant tags of `python` and `c++` so I removed them. Please only use the tags that are appropriate for the language you're asking about.

Comment: Can you explain what the `if` and nested loops are doing in your solution? This is fundamentally an `O(n)` problem.

Comment: Pass 1 through the array accumulates counts in `frequency` — a single loop, not a nested loop.  Pass 2 processes the counted frequencies.  It appears that the range of possible values is fairly small, so you can have an array for the frequencies.

Comment: I don't care about time complexity. Any solution is fine to me. @Neil

Comment: Arrays are accessed by index and not values as you are passing the value ```arr[j]``` as index to ```frequency[arr[j]]```.

Comment: @goku Your histogram is a great way to do it, but you need one pass; anything more and you are doing a more complex problem, some sort of convolution.

Comment: If you do not care about time complexity, this program becomes much simpler if you first sort the array.

Comment: @Chris the code becomes more time efficient if we sort the array!

Comment: What should I do after I sort it? @Chris

Comment: If you have the array sorted, then you iterate over it and just don't display any elements that are the same as the next element.

Comment: What is your expected output for your sample data?  What is the expected output for an array such as `int array[] = { 2, 9, 2, 8, 2, 7, 2, 9, 2, 7, 2, 8, 8 };` — does the sequence of the entries in the output matter?  This also influences whether sorting is an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than nested loops, you need two loops.

One to calculate the frequency. And, another that displays the frequencies and calculates the total number of duplicate numbers.

Here is the refactored code:

**Edit:** I've removed my broken original code during the second update.

---

**UPDATE:**

> Yes but it still displays the same element more than once –
> goku

Oops, my bad ... Here is one that indexes into the frequency table on the second loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define Frequency_size      10000

void
non_unique_numbers(int arr[], int size)
{
    int i;
    int freq;
    int totdup = 0;

    int frequency[Frequency_size] = { 0 };

    // calculate freqency
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        ++frequency[arr[i]];

    for (i = 0; i < Frequency_size; i++) {
        freq = frequency[i];
        if (freq <= 0)
            continue;

        printf("Number: %d  , Frequency: %d\n", i, freq);

        if (freq >= 2)
            ++totdup;
    }

    printf("The number of duplicated numbers is: %d\n",totdup);
}
```

---

**UPDATE #2:**

> Can we make it work for also negative elements? `for (i = 0; i < Frequency_size; i++) { freq = frequency[i]; if (freq <= 0) continue; printf("Number: %d , Frequency: %d\n", i, freq);` Because of this part it is not working for negative integers –
> goku

Yes, we just need to use a second array for the negative number frequencies and index it by the negative of the negative number. (i.e.) we use a corresponding *positive* index.

Also, some have commented about doing range checks, so I've added that along with some statistics on the out of range values [if any]. I've also updated the `if` test so that only *duplicate* numbers are printed.

Once again, I've compiled this but *not* tested it, but it should be okay:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define Frequency_size      10000

void
non_unique_numbers(const int *arr, int size)
{
    int i;
    int freq;
    int val;
    int totdup = 0;
    int pos_badcnt = 0;
    int pos_badmax = 0;
    int neg_badcnt = 0;
    int neg_badmax = 0;

    static int freq_pos[Frequency_size];
    static int freq_neg[Frequency_size];

    // set frequency counts to zero
    memset(freq_pos,0,sizeof(freq_pos));
    memset(freq_neg,0,sizeof(freq_neg));

    // calculate freqency
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        val = arr[i];

        // handle positive number(s)
        if (val >= 0) {
            if (val >= Frequency_size) {
                ++pos_badcnt;
                if (val > pos_badmax)
                    pos_badmax = val;
            }
            else
                ++freq_pos[val];
        }

        // handle negative number(s)
        else {
            // index frequency array with positive index -- that's the trick
            val = -val;

            if (val >= Frequency_size) {
                ++neg_badcnt;
                if (val > neg_badmax)
                    neg_badmax = val;
            }
            else
                ++freq_neg[val];
        }
    }

    // for negative numbers, skip 0 and show lowest (most negative) first
    for (i = Frequency_size - 1;  i >= 1;  --i) {
        freq = freq_neg[i];
        if (freq <= 1)
            continue;

        printf("Number: %d  , Frequency: %d\n", -i, freq);

        ++totdup;
    }

    // show positive number frequencies
    for (i = 0; i < Frequency_size; i++) {
        freq = freq_pos[i];
        if (freq <= 1)
            continue;

        printf("Number: %d  , Frequency: %d\n", i, freq);

        ++totdup;
    }

    printf("The number of duplicated numbers is: %d\n",totdup);

    // show out of range negative number stats
    if (neg_badcnt > 0) {
        printf("There were %d out of range negative numbers\n",neg_badcnt);
        printf("Smallest out of range negative number was %d\n",-neg_badmax);
    }

    // show out of range positive number stats
    if (pos_badcnt > 0) {
        printf("There were %d out of range positive numbers\n",pos_badcnt);
        printf("Largest out of range positive number was %d\n",pos_badmax);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but it still displays the same element more than once. Your output is 
Number: 1  , Frequency: 2
Number: 2  , Frequency: 3
Number: 2  , Frequency: 3
Number: 1  , Frequency: 2
Number: 2  , Frequency: 3
Number: 4  , Frequency: 2
Number: 4  , Frequency: 2
Number: 5  , Frequency: 1

Comment: You could even calculate the duplicates in the first loop by counting the number that become 2's, if you didn't need the second loop.

Comment: That solves the problem. Thank you, I really appreciate it @Craig Estey. So it is solvable without sorting the array too, but less efficient I guess

Comment: The amended code is good.  I'd probably want to add a check that `arr[i]` is in the range `0`..`Frequency_size - 1` to the first loop.  Note that Craig's code has an O(N) complexity — sorting requires O(N•log N) complexity, so for large N, sorting is slower than this.  OTOH, sorting can cope with arbitrary ranges for the values in the array; any code using a `frequency` array requires a lot of space, and doesn't handle negative integers easily, etc.

Comment: Can we make it work for also negative elements?     for (i = 0; i < Frequency_size; i++) {
        freq = frequency[i];
        if (freq <= 0)
            continue;

        printf("Number: %d  , Frequency: %d\n", i, freq); Because of this part it is not working for negative integers

Comment: For negative numbers, we can use a second frequency array. For the frequency array, I used a `Frequency_size` of 10000 (arbitrary to get it to compile). (i.e. the max positive number is 9999) What is your actual number for that? And, (e.g.) with 10000, would the min/lowest negative number be -9999? It would be nice to know the real numbers you're using but I can work with a dummy number. But, it the range is large enough, it won't fit on the stack, so we'd have to add `static` to the array(s).

Comment: My array consists of 20 elements. Not very large. It does have some negative repeating numbers. You're code seems to be working but to be honest I did not know the static method so it is hard for me to understand at the moment. And again thanks for the effort. @CraigEstey

Comment: `static` inside a _function_ (i.e. "function scoped") operates just like a file scope global _except_ that is "private" to the function that declares it. For 20 elements, the TL;DR is just remove it. It's equivalent to: `int freq_pos[20]; /* this is private to non_unique_numbers */ void non_unique_numbers(const int *arr,int size) { ... }`

Comment: You could use a bit-mask on your data before putting it in the histogram to avoid the two tables; I suppose then you'd call it a hash map.

Comment: @Neil _If_ we have a _hard_ limit on the range of negative numbers we _can_ do it in a single array (e.g.) `arr[val + max_neg]`. And, we can do it with just 2 bits / element (e.g. 0x00=unused, 0x01=one, 0x02=two or more, 0x03=reserved). I considered those but wanted to stay somewhat within the code OP already had.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
void non_unique_numbers(int arr[], int size){

    int i,j;
    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        int frequency=0; 
        bool wasFoundEarlier=false;

        for(j=i; j<size; j++)
        {
            if(arr[i]==arr[j])
            {
                frequency++;
            }
        }
        
        for(int x=0;x<i;x++)
        {
            if(arr[x]==arr[i])
            {
                wasFoundEarlier=true;
            }
        }
        
        if(!wasFoundEarlier)
        {
            printf("Number: %d  , Frequency: %d\n", arr[i], frequency);
        }
        
    }
}
```

This will print the frequency of all the elements.

If you want to print the frequency of only duplicate ones, just change the inner loop
 `for(j=i+1; j<size; j++)`

Comment: That also works. Thank you very much.

Comment: This has much more work to do than the other answers, O(`size`^2) _vs_ O(`size`), but it is also in-place, O(1) extra space; that is nice if you are concerned about memory and not concerned about time.